# Como filtrar registro de uma Lista dentro de outra lista c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Possuo uma classe de `App` onde nessa classe contém uma `ICollection<Comentarios>`

Agora preciso filtrar TODOS os **comentários** que tiverem `Status == Aprovado`, onde esse Status é um enum.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```cs
IEnumerable<App> app = await GetAsync(
    c => c.Comments.Where(d => d.Status == Status.Approved)
);
```

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
{ 
    return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync(); 
}
```

é retornado o erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Vitrine.Core.Entities.Comment>'
> to 'bool'

Comment: Como está esse método? `GetAsync`

Comment: @Marconi         public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: Só `await GetAsync(d => d.Status == Status.Approved);` não funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando EF Core 5, pode fazer um `Include` com filtro. Veja mais [neste post sobre as novidades do EF Core 5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include).

```cs
var apps = _dbContext.Set<App>()
               .Include(a => a.Comentarios.Where(c => c.Status == Status.Approved));
```